# pigpio - set_PWM_dutycycle vs hardware_PWM

Tags: gpio, pi-2, pwm, pigpio

What is the difference between the [set_PWM_dutycycle](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html#set_PWM_dutycycle) function and the [hardware_PWM](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html#hardware_PWM) function in the pigpio python library when assuming the same frequency is set for both the functions. Will I get a more stable output from one versus the other? I'm using the Pi 2 Model B and need 4 separate PWM signals with different outputs but same frequency.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[hardware_PWM](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html#set_PWM_dutycycle) >>> [set_PWM_dutycycle](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html#hardware_PWM[hardware_PWM]) >>> software PWM

where >>> is orders of magnitude better pulse stability.

[hardware_PWM](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html#set_PWM_dutycycle)

- rock solid pulses
- large choice and range of frequencies
- large number of steps between off and fully on

[set_PWM_dutycycle](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html#hardware_PWM[hardware_PWM])

- very stable pulses, unlikely to be affected by anything other than sustained heavy network traffic.
- 18 different frequencies (8000, 4000, 2000, 1600, 1000, 800, 500, 400, 320, 250, 200, 160, 100, 80, 50, 40, 20, 10)
- limited steps between off and fully on (25 at 8000Hz, 250 at 800Hz, 4000 at 50Hz)

software PWM

- stability depends on system activity, will be better on the four core Pi2 compared to single core Pis.  Servos will jitter and LEDs will flash when the system is busy.
- infinite choice and range of frequencies
- infinite number of steps between off and fully on

Comment: Thanks for this great answer. Can you explain briefly how hardware_PWM and set_PWM_dutycycle differ internally? Like, how do they work internally?